# Reading Mysql database in groups of 10

Tags: php, mysql

I need to be able to read the contents of a Mysql database 10 records at a time so that i can display the first 10 and then when the user click on page 2, i need to be able to read the second block of 10 records with out the first 10, etc, etc

this is what im using to read the first 10

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM general_thread WHERE id_topic = $id");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_message, user_created, user_id, user_posts, user_rank, date_created FROM general_thread WHERE id_topic = $id ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_message, user_created, user_id, user_posts, user_rank, date_created FROM general_thread WHERE id_topic = $id ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10, 10;")`

For the next 10? Then

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_message, user_created, user_id, user_posts, user_rank, date_created FROM general_thread WHERE id_topic = $id ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 20, 10;")`

For the 10 after that?

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: ill be marking it as the answer asap :)